How to set up CORS in Laravel to allow credentials and specific origins?
I’m working on a Laravel application that needs to handle CORS for requests coming from a Vue 3 frontend. I am encountering a CORS error related to credentials, and I need help configuring CORS correctly in my Laravel backend.
I receive the following error when trying to make an XMLHttpRequest from my Vue application to my Laravel backend:
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/oauth/token' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:5173' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response is '' which must be 'true' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.


https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/routing#cors

You can handle CORS in Laravel by manually setting the appropriate headers in your middleware. Here's how you can do it:
This solution is for older laravel versions, for laravel 11+,
run:
php artisan config:publish cors

and adjust your settings in the cors config
For older Laravel version follow these steps:
1. Create a Custom Middleware
create a custom middleware that will handle the CORS settings:
php artisan make:middleware HandleCors

2. Configure the Middleware
open the newly created HandleCors.php file and modify it to include the necessary CORS headers:
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class HandleCors
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $response = $next($request);

        $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://127.0.0.1:5173'); // or other domain
        $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
        $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization');
        $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');

        // Handle preflight requests
        if ($request->getMethod() === 'OPTIONS') {
            $response->setStatusCode(200);
            return $response;
        }

        return $response;
    }
}

3. Register the Middleware
Register the middleware in the app/Http/Kernel.php file. You can either add it to the global middleware stack or just to the api middleware group:
protected $middleware = [
    // ...
    \App\Http\Middleware\HandleCors::class,
    // ...
];

// OR in the $middlewareGroups for 'api'

protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'api' => [
        // ...
        \App\Http\Middleware\HandleCors::class,
    ],
];

4. Clear Configuration Cache (if needed)
If you encounter any issues, clear the configuration cache:
php artisan config:cache


It was not available before laravel 11, so if the project is on laravel 11 it will be best, if not then this is the way
